# How to Hide Hamburger Menu icon in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to hide the hamburger menu on certain pages but still hamburger menu icon is visible in some of the pages . I have a tried a possible ways but nothing helped us. And I attached a image for your Reference.

[image: hamburger Menu icon come like this]

Possible case I tried so far:

In Xaml Page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             BackgroundColor="#F8F8F8"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
</ContentPage>
```

Xaml.cs (Code Behind)

I put the code in constructor, and this also not helped

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```

And I used **ShouldShowToolbarButton** in Flyout Page also ,

```
public static bool showIcon;

public override bool ShouldShowToolbarButton()
{
    return showIcon;
}
```

I tried possible combinations but hamburger icon is still visible only. Most probably am facing this issue in Android

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Is your project a shell app? I had tried the ShouldShowToolbarButton in my flyoutpage of my project and it worked wel

Comment: No, My app is not shell app

Comment: But when I used your code about the ShouldShowToolbarButton in my flyoutpage, the hamburger button didn't show.

Comment: But in my app it shows the Hamburger icon

Comment: You can try to set the value of the showIcon as false and update the xamrin.forms to the lastest version.

Comment: I Updated Xamarin Forms also to Up-To date also But still hamburger icon /back button is coming